# DataSnap Mobile Connectors for a DataSnap REST server

Tags: rest, datasnap, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am using Rad Studio Tokyo 10.2.3
I am build a mobile application for Android and iOS which will connect to a DataSnap REST server.
My question is about the connection between the mobile application and the DataSnap REST server.
I am planning to just create a REST Client in the mobile application.
And then I saw that article:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Getting_Started_with_DataSnap_Mobile_Connectors

The DataSnaop server will be built with Delphi.
I know that another option will be to create a proxy file at the server level and then include the proxy file in the mobile application.

What I do not understand is why the proxy file mentioned in the article above is in Objective-C for iOS, Java for Android, etc.. ?
Because the mobile application is a multi-device application written in C++ builder.
Why I can't just create a proxy file in C++ at the DataSnap server level and integrate it in my application or just use the REST Client I created?
What kind of connector is mentioned in the above article about?

Comment: I think I got the difference!
The proxy generated by the Rest Client wizard or TSQLConnection are for the development.
And the mobile connectors mentioned in the article with the link above are for the deployment on iOS and Android platforms?

Comment: The Mobile connectors are from the days before EMBT had compilers for mobile platforms.